# How to redirect www dns from Exchange server to a remote host

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, exchange-2007, internal-dns

Our exchange server domain is queensberry.com

The way this has been setup (by an external company) is that if I try to browse to our website using queensberry.com rather than www.queensberry.com I am directed to the main exchange box, rather than our actual externally hosted server.

As we would like to drop the www, is it possible to setup a DNS record to that host without breaking the rest of exchange functionality. That server has it's own dns name of exserver.queensbery.com

If it is possible can someone please tell me how or direct me to where I can find instuctions.

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. All is working great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like there is an A record for the domain that points to the ip address of the Exchange server. Change the domain A record to point to the ip address of your web server. This won't affect Exchange except for the fact that people who are used to typing queensberry.com to get to OWA will now have to type mail.queensberry.com (or whatever A or CNAME record you set up to pint to Exchange).

oops. I forgot about the SSL cert for OWA and RPC over HTTP. Are you using SSL and if so, what's the friendly (common) name of the current cert?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the CNAME record for "queensberry.com" to point to the correct server in your DNS records.

Comment: To amplify: change the CNAME record for queesberry.com to that of your external web-server.

Comment: It's going to be an A record, not a CNAME for queensberry.com unless they have a pretty weird setup. I'm not even sure it's possible to CNAME at that level but not 100% sure it's impossible either.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Exchange server is using name-based hosting, the biggest hassle of moving it from queensberry.com to exchange.queensberry.com is getting new SSL certificates to reflect the new name. Everything else should just work.